# HTTP Post failure with angular

Tags: angularjs, post

I am new to angular.js and am unable to get a simple POST request to work.  I am using angular version 1.4.8.  My request never makes it to the server.  Instead, it appears the client errors out before making the request.  I can't see what I'm doing wrong, even though I've read the documentation here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post.  Here is the relevant error info I have (produced with the code example below):

{
    "data": null,
    "status": -1,
    "config": {
      "method": "POST",
      "transformRequest": [
        null
      ],
      "transformResponse": [
        null
      ],
      "url": "http://localhost:4567/foo",
      "data": {
        "foo": "bar"
      },
      "headers": {
        "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
        "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8"
      }
    },
    "statusText": ""
  }

And here is my code example.  It reproduces the problem in both firefox and chrome, so this doesn't seem to be a browser quirk.  Since I'm an angular newbie, this is likely something basic (but not obvious to me).  Help appreciated ;)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('customersCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {

        $scope.httpPost = function (postBody) {
            var successCallback = function (data, status, headers, config) {
                alert("post success");
            };

            var errorCallback = function (data, status, headers, config) {
                var responseJson = angular.toJson(data);
                $scope.theError = responseJson;
            };

            $http.post('http://localhost:4567/foo', postBody).then(successCallback, errorCallback);

        };

        var postBody = {"foo" : "bar"};
        $scope.httpPost(postBody);
    });
</script>

<div data-ng-app="myApp" data-ng-controller="customersCtrl">
    <pre>{{theError}}</pre>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: could you provide more information on the client error?  are you getting anything in either callback?

Comment: I converted the error to json.  It is listed in the second paragraph of the questions.

Comment: I mean, did you print $scope.theError? (just making sure because it seems like you did)  Or where did the error come from? Making sure it is a client error, because the JSON you posted seems like the request is fine / your code looks ok

Comment: The error was printed with this line: <pre>{{theError}}</pre>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I don't know the answer to your question, may I suggest what worked for me? I too am an Angular beginner. Also, have a look at [John Papa's Angular guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide) for better code.

**Front End**

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .config(config);

function config($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/add-job', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/add-job.view.html',
        controller: AddController,
        controllerAs: 'addCtrl'
    });
};

function AddController($http) {
    var that = this;

    that.add_new = function (job) {
        $http.post('api/add_job', that.job).success(function () {
            //alert("added!");
        });
    };
}
```

**Back End** - Slim framework

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new \Slim\App; 

$app->post('/add_job', 'addJob');

function addJob($request) {
    $job = json_decode($request->getBody());
    $sql = "INSERT INTO jobs (title, company, location) VALUES (:title, :company, :location)";
    try {
        $db = getConnection();
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);  
        $stmt->bindParam("title", $job->title);
        $stmt->bindParam("company", $job->company);
        $stmt->bindParam("location", $job->location);
        $stmt->execute();
        $job->id = $db->lastInsertId();
        $db = null;
        echo json_encode($job); 
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}'; 
    }
}
```

**View**

```
<form novalidate name="AddNewForm" method="post" action="">

    <input type="text" ng-model="addCtrl.job.title" placeholder="Title" /><br/>
    <input type="text" ng-model="addCtrl.job.company" placeholder="Company" /><br/>
    <input type="text" ng-model="addCtrl.job.location" placeholder="Location" /><br/>

    <button ng-click="addCtrl.add_new(job)">Save!</button>

</form>
```

Comment: Hi Ivan, thanks for the quick response.  I am having a hard time understanding the front end code.  Could you put it into the context of an html document as in my question.  Your answer might work; I'm new enough I'm not sure how to wire it into a working example ;)

Comment: @user1483903 I added the HTML view. Have a look. This is the main thing `ng-click="addCtrl.add_new(job)"` which calls `$http.post('api/add_job', that.job)`.

Comment: @user1483903 What also helps is using the Chrome debugger by pressing F12. Go on the network tab and refresh the page. Then click on the file in XHR and see what status you get for your request.

Comment: Your suggestion to use the chrome debugger pointed me in the right direction.  This was a CORS problem.  I accessed this web page as a flat file, ie: file:///my-angular-post.html.  The web service it talks to runs in a web container.  When I added the static html file to the web server my original code works.  Thanks!

Comment: It would have been nice if the browser and/or angular could have given a CORS error message in the first place!